# Detect row selection in wxGrid

Tags: events, wxpython

I would like to be warned when user selects the whole row in a wxGrid but I do not see an event that handles this.What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `EVT_GRID_RANGE_SELECT`, and then check that the range is a single row when the handler is called.

For example, in the GridSimple.py wxPython demo, put the line in `SimpleGrid.__init__`

```
    self.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_RANGE_SELECT, self.OnSelectRange)
```

And then add this to see which cells were selected.

```
def OnSelectRange(self, evt):
    print "on select range", evt.GetTopLeftCoords(), evt.GetBottomRightCoords()
```

From this you can determine whether the selection was one that you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I figured it out. There are events like EVT_GRID_LABEL_LEFT_CLICK and then I test event.GetCol() == -1, to make sure the click is on a whole row, not a whole column.

Comment: Do you also check for multiple row selections? If so, I would be interested in how you did that.